# Nested attributes has_many passing and collecting ids to build model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have this form:

```
<% form_tag add_expt_details_samples_path, :method => :post do %>
    <% for sample in @samples %>
        <% if sample.study_id == @study.id %>
            <% fields_for "samples[]", sample do |form| %>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Sample Name: <%= sample.name %></legend>
                    <p><center><%= form.label :sample_title %>
                    <%= form.text_field :sample_title, :size => 25 %></center></p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= form.label :taxon_id %>
                                <%= form.text_field :taxon_id, :size => 15 %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= form.label :scientific_name %>
                                <%= form.text_field :scientific_name, :size => 20 %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= form.label :common_name %>
                                <%= form.text_field :common_name, :size => 15 %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p>
                        <center>
                            <%= form.label :sample_descripition %><br \>
                            <%= form.text_area :description %>
                        </center>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
             <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
        <p><center><%= submit_tag "Next" %></center></p>
<% end %>
```

I would like to collect the samples[] in add_expt_details action so that I could render a post method view for adding new model records for the samples[] ids.

my action is as follows

```
def add_expt_details
    # Collect the samples that were sent
    @expt_samples = Sample.find(params[:samples])
    # @expt_samples.each do |samp|
    #   samp.expts.build
    # end
  end
```

and then send them to a create action where the sample details are updated and the expt values can be created.

```
def create_study
    @samples = Sample.update(params[:samples].keys, params[:samples].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
      if @samples.empty? 
        flash[:notice] = "Samples updated"
        redirect_to :action => "add_expt_details", :anchor => "ok"
      else
        render :action => 'edit_individual'
      end
  end
```

is there a way to achieve this, I have used accepted_nested_attributes_for :expts, :dependent => :destroy. But I seem to be wrong some where and I do not want to have a form with many fields.

The error message I get is "Unknown key(s): 3, 6, 12"

All suggestions are appreciated.